# how to speed up training process

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I'm using `sklearn` to train a classification model, the data shape and training pipeline is:

```
clf = Pipeline([
    ("imputer", Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy="mean", axis=0)),
    ('feature_selection', VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.97 * (1 - .97)))),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('classification', svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1))])

print X.shape, y.shape
(59381, 895) (59381,)
```

I have checked that `feature_selection` will reduce the feature vector size from `895` to `124`

```
feature_selection = Pipeline([
    ("imputer", Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy="mean", axis=0)),
    ('feature_selection', VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.97 * (1 - .97))))
    ])

feature_selection.fit_transform(X).shape
(59381, 124) (59381,)
```

then I try to get accuracy as below

```
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X, y)
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
```

but the training process is very slow, I want to know to speed up the process in this situation? or the size of feature vector `124` is still too large to `svm` model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `sklearn.svm.LinearSVC`.

It suppose to give very similar results to `svm.SVC(kernel='linear')`, but training process will be faster(at least when `d<m`, when d-feature dimension and m- size of train sample).

If you want to use other kernel, like `rbf`, you can't use `LinearSVC`.

However, you can add kernel cache size:  the size of the kernel cache has a strong impact on run times for larger problems. If you have enough RAM available, it is recommended to set `cache_size` to a higher value than the default of 200(MB), such as 500(MB) or 1000(MB).